# How to dynamically construct MongoDB Criteria object for Aggregation.match?

Tags: java, spring-data-mongodb

I have the following JSON object which I would like to convert to a `Criteria` object so that I can use in `Aggregation.match()` query.

```json
{
  "_filter": {
    "$and": [
      {
        "$or": [
          {
            "country": "India"
          },
          {
            "age": 20
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "_page": {
    "pageNum": 0,
    "recordsPerPage": 1
  }
}
```

I have seen that we have `BasicQuery` object which can be constructed from the contents of the `_filter` field. However, I am not able to deduce `Criteria` object from that.

Is there any method/utility in Spring Data MongoDB that does this?

Answer (score 1):

Actually `Criteria` is a wrapper class to abstract you from the MongoDB syntax and build the queries in an elegant way.

> I would like to convert to a `Criteria` object so that I can use in `Aggregation.match()` query

There is no need to do so. Try this:

```
AggregationOperation match = ctx => new Document("$match", Document.parse(your_json).get("_filter"));
...
Aggregation agg = Aggregation.newAggregation(match)
   .withOptions(Aggregation.newAggregationOptions().allowDiskUse(Boolean.TRUE).build());
mongotemplate.aggregate();
mongoTemplate.aggregate(agg, inputType, outputType).getMappedResults();
```